# How to wait async function is done processing in flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await

I make `initPlatformState` .. an async function to detect mock location and after the process of `initPlatformState` function is finished I need to do something...but the problem is... because `initPlatformState` is working asynchronously and I am not putting `initPlatformState` inside `initState`... `initPlatformState` will work before it is not done yet... is there a way to wait `initPlatformState` has done doing the process and then I will do something else?
here is my code

```
bool canMockLocation=false;
initPlatformState() async {
    if (!mounted) return;
    try {
      canMockLocation = await TrustFall.canMockLocation;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }

    setState(() {
      canMockLocation = canMockLocation;
    });
  }

_getData() async {
       setState(() {
        load = true;
      });
      initPlatformState();
      setState(() {
        load = false;
      });
       if(canMockLocation){
        show alert;
       }else{
        print("check");
       }
```

and here is for my widget

```
             Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      loadLocation
                          ? Text("Loading...") 
                          : Text("Success")
             .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add await where you are calling this method. await will hold position till function process is not complete.

```
await initPlatformState();
```

Comment: I wanna ask.. you said that await will hold until the process is not complete... what do you mean by not complete?

Comment: as your initPlatformState method is async so if you add await where you are calling(in _getData method) then until that function's each line is not executed next line of _getData will not exicuted.

Comment: so using ```await initPlatformState()```...```getData``` will be executed until the process inside ```initPlatformState()``` is done... is that right if I say llike that?

Comment: yes, to be more clear. even this line will be not executed  load = false;